# Variables with super/sub scripts

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions

So I know how to create variable names with subscripts/superscripts at the end (using ctrl+_ etc), however, how would I use them in the middle of a variable name?

Comment: Use an indexed variable and then format it for display anyway that you want. `Format[x[m_, n_]] := Row[{"start", Subsuperscript["x", m, n], "end"}]; x[1, 2]`